# How do I use selectedRowInComponent method for UIPickerView

Tags: iphone

I have a UIPickerView object that has five rows that a user can select. I want to return the index of the row that the user selects on IBAction. When my method is called, I can return the text of the value of what the user selected with this code: 
`NSString * userChoice = [self pickerView:picker titleForRow:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];` 
I want to now return as an NSInteger, the row that is returned. The following code kills the program and I don't know why: 
`NSLog(@"hello?? %@", [picker selectedRowInComponent:0]);`

Any thoughts?? Is there a better method to use besides selectedRowInComponent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
NSLog(@"hello?? %d", [picker selectedRowInComponent:0]);
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I thought that %@ can be used for any object, apparently not for NSIntegers.

Comment: Here's a complete list of format specifiers:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

An NSInteger is not an object it's a typedef for a long or int (see [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html)).

As Aaron pointed out, you can use any of the format specifiers: %d, %D, %i